# Perché è utilizzato l'avverbio "vi" in questa frase?

Tags: adverbs

Vorrei sapere perché si è usato “vi” nella frase

> Bisogna fermarsi quando vi sono pedoni che attraversano la strada

E perché non si è usato invece “ci”?

Comment: Per cominciare non è un articolo (semmai un avverbio). *Vi* e *ci*, quando usati come avverbi di luogo, sono sinonimi e usare l'uno piuttosto che l'altro è una scelta puramente stilistica. Cioè, la frase *Bisogna fermarsi quando ci sono pedoni che attraversano la strada* è una perfettamente corretta alternativa. Questo **non** è vero quando *ci* e *vi* sono usati come pronomi personali complemento (e.g. *Ci davano mele* e *Vi davano mele* non significano la stessa cosa!).

Comment: @DenisNardin Il tuo commento mi sembra una risposta completa, perché non lo trasformi?

Answer (score 7):

La natura grammaticale di *vi*, in questa frase, è avverbio. Secondo il [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/vi1/),

> Avverbio di luogo equivalente a *ivi* (in questo o in quel luogo, là, e per estens. in ciò, a ciò), usato con verbi di stato e di moto; equivale al più comune *ci*, ma è di tono più formale.

Nessuno comincerebbe a raccontare una favola con *v'era una volta*, ma dirà *c'era una volta*, ma è assai probabile che un avvocato impegnato nella sua arringa dica *non vi è alcuna differenza*, mentre, parlando al suo assistito direbbe *non c'è alcuna differenza*.

L'avverbio *vi* viene da *ibi*, mentre *ci* viene da *hic*. I due avverbi sono essenzialmente intercambiabili, ma è effettivamente vero che *vi* è più “ricercato”, “preciso” o, come dice il vocabolario, “formale”. Nel linguaggio parlato è difficile sentire *vi*, che invece è (o era) più usato nello scritto.

---

Sia *vi* sia *ci* hanno subito una trasformazione che li ha portati a essere usati anche come particelle pronominali; se ne trova una descrizione alla [voce “ci”](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ci1/). Quando sono pronomi, non sono intercambiabili, perché *ci* si riferisce alla prima persona plurale (per esempio *a noi*), mentre *vi* alla seconda (per esempio *a voi*).